# ICMP timestamp requests

Tags: linux, security, icmp

Is there a way to disable ICMP timestamp requests without using `iptables` on our RedHat 5 and 6 servers?  We are not using `iptables` because we use a hardware-based firewall.

Is there any setting (say, under `/proc/sys/net/ipv4`) that'll disable replying to ICMP timestamp requests?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can suppress tcp-timestamps that way, but not icmp.